# Why doesn't extra whitespace between rows in a tabular environment work in 50% of cases?

Tags: tables

With this code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}\sf
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Some text: & \textsl{More text} More Text\\[20pt]%works
    & \hspace{0.5cm}\parbox[l][][l]{9cm}{\raggedright \input knuth }\\[20pt]%doesn't work
Some text: & \textsl{More text} {More Text}\\[20pt]
    & \hspace{0.5cm}\parbox[l][][l]{9cm}{\input knuth }\\[20pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I get the extra whitespace between row 1 and 2 and between 3 and 4, but not between 2 and 3. Why?

Comment: Also, `[l][][l]` are not legal arguments for \parbox and are being ignored.  The first optional argument should be`t`,`c` or `b`.  The second should be the height, and the third should be `t`, `c`, `b` or `s`.  BTW, you could add vertical space to the parbox by specifying the height and using [t] for the third argument.

Comment: Yes @L.J.R. that answered my question

Comment: note `\sf` has not been defined by default in latex for almost 30 years, `article` class defines it for compatibility with latex2.09 documents

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that kind of illustrates my age...

Comment: @gctwnl well me too:-)

Answer (score 3):

`\\[20pt]` does not add extra space, it increases the depth of the strut added to the line.  Because you have a nested `\parbox` rather than using a `p` column, the content of the cell already has a depth that is greater than the depth of the extended strut so it has no effect.

If you want to add 20pt of space between the rows, see the booktabs package `\addlinespace` command.